# cannot expose class in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

This may seem like a beginner question, and it kind of is since this is my first large c# project conversion. Currently converting a large project from vb.net to c#, I understand c# syntax pretty well and the conversion is going pretty smoothly. My one question is - in vb.net I could expose a class with the import statement as such:

```
Imports DataAccessLayer.DataAccess
```

and say there is a method called GetDataTable in the DataAccess class, I can just call it by using GetDataTable(params)

Now, with C#, I can only do

```
Using DataAccessLayer;
```

and can't expose the DataAccess class, just the DataAccessLayer namespace and have to do DataAccess.GetDataTable(params), which will obviously add a lot of extra code to the project if I have to do that anywhere.

Is there any way to expose the class and not just the namespace? This is my constructor

```
namespace DataAccessLayer
{
    public class DataAccess
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried doing `Using DataAccessLayer.DataAccess;`?

Comment: yes, that was how my code was in vb.net and it worked fine. it won't allow me to add the .DataAccess, says it doesn't exist.

Comment: What would be the advantage of calling `GetDataTable` without the type identifier? You might as well just confuse it with a private / public method

Comment: What version of C# are you using? Is this in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: [Using Static Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) may be what you are looking for...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using C# v6 or above, you can [import a static class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) like this:

```
using static Namespace.StaticClass;
```

So you can do the same for your class:

```
using static DataAccessLayer.DataAccess;
```

Comment: yep, figured it out right after I posted this. it's a whole new world converting to c#, like i said i've been using java and javascript for years so i'm very familiar with the syntax but some of the subtle things are escaping me

Answer (score 2):

C# 6 supports this as

```
using static DataAccessLayer.DataAccess;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) here you can only access static members of a type without having to qualify the access with the type name like the following:

using static System.Console;

```
using static System.Math;
class Program 
{ 
    static void Main() 
    { 
        WriteLine(Sqrt(3*3 + 4*4)); 
    } 
}
```

You can create an alias for a type though:

```
using Project = PC.MyCompany.Project;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question, for anyone else that runs into this problem - i used

```
using static DataAccessLayer.DataAccess;
```

adding the static made it work.